# Create Index On Complex JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

My query is like below:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT u0_.service_id AS sclr0, u1_.property_uri AS property_uri1, u2_.value AS value2, count(u2_.id) AS sclr3 
FROM usc_connection_triple u2_ 
INNER JOIN usc_property u1_ ON u2_.property_id = u1_.id AND (u1_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ ON u2_.account_connection_id = u3_.id AND (u3_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_service_subscriber u0_ ON ((u3_.account_1_id = u0_.id OR u3_.account_2_id = u0_.id)) AND (u0_.status = 1) 
WHERE (u1_.create_analytics = '1') AND (u2_.status = 1) 
GROUP BY u0_.service_id, u2_.property_id, u2_.value;
```

The current status of explain command is as below(storage engine: innodb):

[image]

Now, I want to create a index on u0_ table. From the columns, I was trying with (service_id, status) (tried with both order), which doesn't seems to work. My assumption is, primary_key will always part of secondary index, thus I don't need to add it exclusively.(still tried and no luck yet).

My question is, can't I get a index working on this table at all in the current situation? I can, how?

Or will any restructuring the query will help?

Answer (score 0):

I always try to put WHERE conditions in the JOINs where possible, I also like to keep my JOIN conditions with the table I am JOINing to on the left of the equals and I prefer IN to OR where possible:

```
  SELECT u0_.service_id sclr0,
         u1_.property_uri property_uri1,
         u2_.value AS value2,
         count(u2_.id) sclr3 
    FROM usc_connection_triple u2_  
    JOIN usc_property u1_ 
      ON u1_.id = u2_.property_id 
     AND u1_.status = 1
     AND u1_.create_analytics = 1
    JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ 
      ON u3_.id = u2_.account_connection_id
     AND u3_.status = 1 
    JOIN usc_service_subscriber u0_ 
      ON u0_.id IN (u3_.account_1_id,u3_.account_2_id)
     AND u0_.status = 1
   WHERE u2_.status = 1
GROUP BY u0_.service_id, u2_.property_id, u2_.value;
```

I also made the assumption that `u1_.create_analytics` was an integer and removed the single quotes.

I'd also double check your GROUP BY, it doesn't match your SELECT.. perhaps you want:

```
GROUP BY sclr0, property_uri1, value2; /* You can use aliases in GROUP BY */
```

As for indexes I'd go for:

- u0_ (id, status, service_id)
- u1_ (id, status, create_analytics, property_uri)
- u2_ (id, status, property_id, account_connection_id, value)
- u3_ (id, status, account_1_id, account_2_id)

I'm not great with indexes and JOINs but use the possible_keys in the EXPLAIN to figure out if these work with the query however or need to be adjusted.

Hope that helps :)